# Remove class previously added not working

Tags: javascript

I'm adding a class to an article with js, its all working, no problem. But if I want to remove that class, this approach wont work. I cannot use jQuery.

```js
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var blogCard = document.querySelectorAll('[data-role="blogCard"]');
            for (let i = 0; i < blogCard.length; i++) {
                blogCard[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    this.classList.add('opened-card');

                    var closeCard = document.querySelectorAll('[data-role="closeCard"]');
                    closeCard[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
                        var pThis = this.parentNode;
                        pThis.classList.remove('opened-card');
                    });

                });
            };

        });
```

```html
    <div class="card" data-role="blogCard">
        <button data-role="closeCard">Close</button>
    </div>
```

I've tried to change 'remove' to 'add' and it worked perfectly, it add the class. But when I go back to remove it wont work.

Answer (score 4):

Because the `click` event propagates to the parent, two click handlers are actually fired here. `button.closeCard` click handler removes the class, but `div.blogCard` one adds it back. :) That's why adding a class works, but removing doesn't.

To solve this, you might either just prevent the event propagation in that second handler, or just use the combined event handler set on `div.blogCard`, choosing the behaviour depending on `event.target` (essentially implementing delegation). Like this:

```
blogCard[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.getAttribute('data-role') === 'closeCard') {
    this.classList.remove('opened-card');
  }
  else {
    this.classList.add('opened-card');
  }
});
```

In fact, you might consider using the same technique - checking the target's position in DOM *inside* event handler - by applying a single event handler to those cards' parent (if there's a single parent, of course):

```
// a single event handler set on some 'cardContainer' element
var blogCard = event.target.closest('[data-role="blogCard"]');
if (blogCard) {
  var action = event.target.closest('[data-role="closeCard"]') ? 'remove' : 'add';
  blogCard.classList[action]('opened-card');
}
```

This, as correctly mentioned by @IronFlare, not only is more performant and easier to read than doing in the loop for each card separately, but also handles all the cards added to the DOM after event handler is set up.

Comment: No problem, happens to all of us. ) When seeing strange things, usually the best idea is to debug it line-by-line to see the big picture.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning event listeners like this in a loop is *possible* as the other answers have shown, but it's **not** the easiest or most efficient option. Using a global click listener with `Element.matches()` conditionals is better because:

- It's simpler and easier to understand in the code.
- It's more efficient and doesn't rely on a synchronous loop immediately after the page becomes interactible.
- It allows you to add additional cards after `DOMContentReady` fires without any special handling; all elements matching the selector at the time of the click will be "heard" by the listener.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Click!", e.target);
  if (e.target.matches("[data-role='blogCard']")) {
    e.target.classList.add('opened-card');
  }
  if (e.target.matches("[data-role='closeCard']")) {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.remove('opened-card');
  }
});
```

```css
.opened-card {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" data-role="blogCard">
  <button data-role="closeCard">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ability to set up eventListeners on specific elements is given to us for a reason. While this approach is certainly possible, there are several caveats. Not only this code will be invoked for each and every click on the page, it silently creates a global assumption, that each 'data-role=closeCard' should trigger removal of `opened-card' on its parent. Besides, if the structure of `blogCard' is changed, no longer `matches` will be sufficient, instead one should check for 'closest(data-role="blogCard") instead.

Comment: Yes, tying event handler to a container is a good idea, but it's hard to suggest without seeing the OP's case whether or not it's close enough to blog cards. The change I mentioned is not live; what if someone decides to add a header div into blogCards, for example? Or make some other modifications in '.blogCard' structure for decoration reasons? This will cause changing in event handler as well, as event.target will no longer be matched by that selector; closest should be used instead.

Comment: Accidentally deleted by first reply, so here's a recreation -- Valid points. You can trivially scope the listener to a parent element instead of the window (e.g. `document.getElementById("cardContainer").addEventListener`) which addresses your first two concerns. As for the last concern, having one listener to handle all of the elements at once actually makes it easier to modify, but if the structure of the card and the criteria for closing them changes *while* the page is live, that's an implementation problem with the cards themselves.

Comment: I think for the same reasons as you mentioned -- that we don't know the full content of the card, it's hard to justify one solution over the other. Your `if (close button) else` is also vulnerable to the same "changing requirements" problem. I stand by the notion that a non-looped event listener for all elements at once reflects better practice, in general. See [Event Delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate)

Comment: Did I say anything against event delegation as a technique - especially considering it's used in the answer? )) Of course not; it's all about implementation: 1) do not set up the event handler too high in DOM (as you'll end up having a lot of things just hanging there - both functions and their scope); 2) instead of `.matches`, check for `.closest`, as any change in DOM will break your delegation.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you add an event to the first "closeCard" in the document everytime you "open" a card.

This would not work if you have more than 1 card.

Try adding 2 separate events:

```js
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            // get blogCards
            var blogCard = document.querySelectorAll('[data-role="blogCard"]');
            // get closeCards
            var closeCard = document.querySelectorAll('[data-role="closeCard"]');

            for (let i = 0; i < blogCard.length; i++) {
                // apply open event 
                blogCard[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    this.classList.add('opened-card');
                });
                // apply respective close event
                // this assumes you have one close button for every blogCard
                // if it's not the case then maybe you should scope the querySelectors
                closeCard[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    var pThis = this.parentNode;
                    pThis.classList.remove('opened-card');
                });

            };
        });
```

This code can be optimized (you don't need to query for both "roles" individually if you know the DOM relation between the blogCard and the closeCard) but I'll leave that to OP